# How to extract unrounded value from excel cell?

Tags: java, excel, jxl

Suppose a cell in an excel sheet contains a value `1500.92`. 
For example:

```
Employee Name | Salary
ABC           | 1500.92
```

and I need to extract salary column as a `string`. That is, I want `1500.92` instead of rounded value `1501`.

I tried using `getContents()` method but it returns `1501` and not `1500.92`.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure anymore, but try this:

```
WritableCell cell = sheet2.getWritableCell(i, j); 
NumberFormat twodecs = new NumberFormat("#.##"); 
WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(twodecs); 
cell.setFormat(cellFormat);
```

Comment: Thanx for your solution, will definitely this as well. I used Decimal format change instead and set the maximum decimal limit.